# How to avoid infinite loop while referencing objects to themselves?

Tags: php, object, infinite-loop

Let's say I want to have a list of people (the amount of people is constant). Now, imagine each person MUST be friend with all the other people (it's not creepy because the order of assigning friends matters). Obviously the friends are human and of the same type of object.

I am defining the class as follows:

```
class Person
{
    public $friends = [];

    function new_freind($person)
    {
        // $person is passed as an object of the same type
        $this->friends[] = $person;
    }
}
```

As a result, the program goes in an infinite-loop because of referencing objects to each other forever.

I was wondering if you could share your idea to prevent the issue.
My idea was to store some sort of keys inside `$friends` instead of the actual objects.

Comment: Please provide a short example to show what the problem is.

Comment: @NigelRen Updated. Hope I could make it clear

Comment: The given code does not produce any infinite loop

Comment: @NicoHaase When I try to print them I see nothing but infinite *RECURSION*

Answer (score 0):

Each person has own ID:

```
class Person {
    static $index = 0;

    public $id;

    public function __constructor() {
        $this->id = ++self::$index;
    }
```

---

When assigning check if `$this->id !== $person->id`